# How do I use jquery to make a background image change on click to a url in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing, onclick

I have this.  (shortened down for this post to not be pointless filler):

```
var randomQuote = function() {
    var quotes = [{
      author: "Duke Nukem: Manhatten Project",
      quote: "Come on out, Morphix. There's just two ways this can end, and in both of them, you die!",
      boxart: "http://game-server-hosting.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/4235.jpg"
    }];
    var numQuotes = quotes.length;
    var randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * numQuotes);
    var quotation = quotes[randomIndex - 1];
    $('.quotebox').html(quotation.quote);
    $('.authorbox').html(quotation.author);
  };
```

I understand how something like this works:

```
$('#bg').css({backgroundImage: "url("+imgbg+")"});
```

What I want to know is how do I instead make it to where that background image changes from what is there to the boxart part of the array instead of a plain url?  Do I use quotation.boxart?  And if so, how?  I've tried a few ways that don't seem to work:

```
$('body').css({'background-image': quotation.boxart});
$('body').css({'background-image': 'quotation.boxart'});
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(quotation.boxart)'});
```

If there's another way I don't know yet (since I'm just learning) any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(' + quotation.boxart + ')'});`

Comment: Ah hah!  I needed the +'s in there.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It was, as Johnny put the 'url(' + quotation.boxart + ')'

Putting in the +'s did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numQuotes);
var quotation = quotes[randomIndex];
$(document.body).css({'background-image':'url("'+quotation.boxart+'")'});
```

Comment: That's what I needed to know, but Johnny clued me in to the +'s needing on there.  var quotation = quotes[randomIndex - 1]; needs the -1 in there still, though.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * numQuotes)` gives you a random integer in [0,numQuotes). So you don't need `-1`.

Comment: Can't it potentially try to go above how many indexes there are by 1 if you don't?

Comment: No. Since `Math.random()` gives you a number in [0,1). `Math.floor(Math.random() * numQuotes)` gives you a random integer in [0,numQuotes). `Math.floor(Math.random() * numQuotes)-1` gives you a random integer in [-1,numQuotes-1).

Comment: So the random number could not make it * 15 = 14.5 or higher to make round round up to 15 if I had 15 indexes in the array?  Honestly just trying to understand what I thought I had read.

Comment: The most important part of this is that it works anyway, regardless, with the -1 and without it, exactly as I had it above.  If it was math.floor, I see what you're getting at.  I was still thinking in terms of what I am sticking with, haha!  Now I get why you're saying that.